# Setting julia project when using pyjulia

Tags: python, julia

I am using pyjulia to call a julia project from python.  I want to use all the packages that are part of my julia package so I want to init the julia runtime from my project directory.  Using `jl_init_path` doesn't seem to work for this.  Is there a pyjulia option or should I use Pkg.activate().

```
import julia
j = julia.Julia(jl_init_path="/path/to/project/")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

```
from julia import Pkg, Main
Pkg.activate("../Project.jl/")
Main.include("../Project.jl/example.jl")
```